# Finding percentage of our closed/won opportunities that were inbound versus outbound in SQL using Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

We’re trying to get the percentage of our closed/won opportunities that were inbound versus outbound (when they were leads)

So far we have this code but are getting an error:

```
Select LeadSource, (count(‘Inbound’) from LeadSource * 100 / select count 
(LeadSource) from Leads)) as percent
Inner join opportunities_T on Leads_T.LeadID = opportunities_T.LeadID
Where opportunities_T.stage = ‘7-Closed/Won’
```

Here are the tables:

```
create table Opportunities_T
(Executive varchar(50) not null,
 AccountName varchar(150) not null,
 Stage varchar(50) not null,
 OpAmount int not null,
 CloseDate date not null,
 AccountStatus varchar(15) not null,
 LeadID int not null,
 constraint Opportunities_PK primary key (LeadID, AccountName),
 constraint Opportunities_FK1 foreign key (LeadID) references Leads_T(LeadID),
 constraint Opportunities_FK2 foreign key (AccountName) references Account_T(AccountName));
```

Table 2:

```
create table Leads_T
(Contact varchar(25),
Company varchar(100),
Title varchar(150),
LeadSource varchar(30),
BDR varchar(50),
LeadID int,
constraint Leads_PK primary key (LeadID));
```

Comment: Non ascii `‘` wont be helping you

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: `Where opportunities_T.stage = ‘7-Closed/Won’` the single quotes are not ascii single quotes they are `‘` and `’` and not `'`

Comment: I fixed it but am  still getting this error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from LeadSource * 100 / select count (LeadSource) from Leads)) as percent Inner ' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the percentages of inbound in the Leads_T table, and link it to your other table that I filled in with dummy data. If you play with the fiddle it should give different percentages based on the number of inbound that match the stage 7 closed. If you need it more specific I would update your main question with some data that more closely matches what you have, right now 66% of the lead source count is inbound, compared to 50% that are inbound and closed.

```
Select LeadSource, (Count('Inbound')* 100 / (Select Count(*) From Leads_T)) 
as Percentage
From Leads_T Inner join opportunities_T on Leads_T.LeadID = 
opportunities_T.LeadID
Where opportunities_T.stage = '7-Closed/Won'
Group By LeadSource
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd8f53/1

Comment: So I corrected the 2nd Leadsource to "Leads_T" and now I have : Select LeadSource, (count('Inbound') from Leads_T* 100 / select count (LeadSource) from Leads_T)) as percent
Inner join opportunities_T on Leads_T.LeadID = opportunities_T.LeadID
Where opportunities_T.stage = '7-Closed/Won';

Comment: but I am still getting an error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from Leads_T* 100 / select count (LeadSource) from Leads_T)) as percent Inner jo' at line 1

Comment: @Elizabeth Updated my answer and added a fiddle.

Comment: Thank you!! However on the fiddle it says the inbound % is 66 and outbound is 33% but when I run the query in mysql it shows me 82% outbound and 15% inbound and a bunch of others listed...

Comment: @Elizabeth is that correct for your data set? My fiddle only have 6 items I threw in real quickly to test.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that we need the opportunities in there because that’s where we can stipulate on closed/won and I think in the code you wrote, you removed the opportunities table

Comment: @Elizabeth updated again, I used dummy data to assume what is in the other table, if it doesn't work for your needs I would need dummy data closer to your needs to try to solve it.